# How I can make some condition for my DatePicker dialog into my android application?

Tags: android, datepicker

please someone help me.I am puzzled at how to deal with the DatePicker and the timePiker  dialog i try to develop an application for car booking so my application 
Contains this diffrent component departure date, return date, departure time, return time
my first question is how i can control +- component block the button - for month when date is for exemple the date for of today my second question when return date Greater then the departure date i wannna show  a toast to alert the user

Comment: could you maybe be a little clearer on what you are asking

Comment: The application is objective to booking cars so i have two  datepicker dialog the first problem is how i can Forced user to chose  departure date for this and  Greater it not be last day :( and show a tosat for the user when the departure date Greater then the return date help me please :) here my source code

Comment: just compare the dates

Comment: and this exemple sir like if i have 25/03/2014 departure time the user can not change the day for 24 or 23 .....